# Remember id and password after first login

Tags: c#, authentication

I'm working in C# with SQL and I have a Windows Form.

In my application I have to login. When I first enter my id and password and login successfully my id and correct password should be saved. After this, whenever I open that application again, I only want to write my id. The password field should be filled automatically.

How can this be done in a C# Windows Forms application?

Best Regards,
Huma Satti

Comment: You have to format your question .

Answer (score 0):

i don't think this as login is very good thing but the easy way to do it by adding a bit field in you users table and set it to true when user logs for first time and then when this is true on login from just fill the textbox with passowrd
Best Regards,
Iordan

Answer (score 0):

Is this not completely bypassing the idea of login security?